# merge audio and video

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4, avfoundation

I have an app in which I need to merge audio file into video file.

Some time my audio file is larger than video file duration. I had use AVFoundation's MixComposition, both get merged. but the problem is that if video file duration is smaller then when video is finished sound still goes on play and complete its full duration. It should be if video is finished audio must get stop.

Could any one provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to stop your audio and it also create fade audio in last five second

```
- (void)getFadeAudioFile {

    if (![appDelegate.musicFilePath isEqualToString:@"Not set"]) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:appDelegate.musicFilePath]autorelease];

        AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:url options:nil]autorelease];

        NSString *filePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
        NSString *outputFilePath = nil;
        outputFilePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/mySong.m4a"];
        NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:outputFilePath]autorelease];

        NSError *theError = nil;

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:&theError];

        [self exportAsset:audioAsset toFilePath:outputFileUrl];

    }
}

- (BOOL)exportAsset:(AVAsset *)avAsset toFilePath:(NSURL *)filePath {

    // get the first audio track
    NSArray *tracks = [avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    if ([tracks count] == 0) return NO;

    AVAssetTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];

    // create the export session
    // no need to retain here since the session will be retained by the
    // completion handler since it is referenced there

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:avAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    if (nil == exportSession) return NO;

    NSLog(@"arrOfImagesForVideo.coun:%d",arrImageDataDict.count);

    int imgCount = arrImageDataDict.count+1;
    int delay = appDelegate.delaySecond;

    int duration = imgCount*delay;

    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake(duration, 1);

    // create trim time range - 20 seconds starting from 30 seconds into the asset
   // NSInteger totalTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(avAsset.duration);

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1);
    //CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake(totalTime, 1);//0,30
    CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

    // create fade in time range - 10 seconds starting at the beginning of trimmed asset
    NSInteger fadeTime = duration-5;

    NSLog(@"fade time:%d",fadeTime);
    NSLog(@"fade duration:%d",duration);

    CMTime startFadeInTime = CMTimeMake(fadeTime, 1);
    CMTime endFadeInTime = CMTimeMake(duration, 1);
    CMTimeRange fadeInTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startFadeInTime, endFadeInTime);

    // setup audio mix
    AVMutableAudioMix *exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];

    [exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0.0 timeRange:fadeInTimeRange]; 
    exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:exportAudioMixInputParameters];   

    // configure export session  output with all our parameters
    exportSession.outputURL = filePath; // output path
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;          // output file type
    exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;                  // trim time range
    exportSession.audioMix = exportAudioMix;                    // fade in audio mix

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
            ^(void ) {
                //[self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath];
            }
            ];

    return YES;
}
```

It will be saved in your file path documents directory and use it like

```
NSString *filePath = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
NSString *outputFilePath1 = [filePath tringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/mySong.m4a"];

NSURL *audio_inputFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:outputFilePath1];
int imgCount = imageArray.count;
int delay = appDelegate.delaySecond;

NSLog(@"audio merged");
int duration = imgCount*delay;

CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(duration, 1);

AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, seekingCM);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition MutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
//[audioAsset autorelease];
newAudioTrack = [audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio][0];
```